# Invert the dependency of gems in order to reuse code?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have several shared behaviours re-used in several projects.

For simplicity, let's just limit this to 2 projects, P1, P2

P1: gem "g1" in `Gemfile`

P2: gem "g1" in `Gemfile`

and the shared behaviour to just 1 gem: G1

G1 defines

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_images

  def cover_image
    product_images.first.url
  end
end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  def url
    # anything
  end
end
```

(it's more complex than this, but I can keep it as simple as this and focus on the idea).

Problem is: this code depends heavily on G1's dependencies `ActiveRecord::Base`, and this is something I'd expect, as it's a key aspect of the success and simplicity of ruby gems. But it doesn't quite seem it's the solution for sharing code across very domain-specific projects.

For sure this is not a new problem, but all the solutions I've seen around seem to overcomplicate the folder organization, need to re-define or even re-run the specs, or simply have lack of structure and leave the responsibility of keeping a decent correctness to the developer.

The solution I have in mind is simple:

G1 becomes:

```
module CoverImage
  def cover_image
    product_images.first.url
  end
end

module ImageUrl
  def url
    # anything
  end
end
```

used by the client projects in this way:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CoverImage

  has_many :product_images
end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageUrl
end
```

this is **very** clean, but it has 1 problem: the gem relies on the client to implement certain methods; at all effects it inverts the dependency from `client -> gem` to `gem -> client`
And it might get even nastier, with something like

```
module ProductRelations
  included do
    has_many :product_images
  end
end
```

which needs the client app to include ActiveRecord, or it won't work.

Though, it's a solution that solves several problems, the biggest one being the possibility to have different `ActiveRecord` versions in the different clients, but it does indeed violate the gem self-containment principle.

Is it something I should worry about?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem, because you want to ensure that the users of your gem implement the methods it depends on.

There are no standard ways to ensure it on language level in Ruby. However, one possible way of getting around it would be defining those methods in your gem module and have them fail gracefully at runtime if not implemented by the user (preferably, stating the *expectations* you have from this method):

```
def product_images
  raise NotImplementedError, 'please implement product_images method that returns an array of image urls'
end
```

Provided that users of your gem would do a good job and use TDD or cover usages of your gem with tests extensively, this problem would be avoided.

Comment: I quite like this approach. What about having also some mandatory configuration? like `include CoverImage.config product_images: product_images` and `module CoverImage; def self.config(settings) ... end; end` ? would it make any sense ?

Comment: I would say it doesn't make much sense to do it in Ruby. It would still fail at runtime, maybe just a bit earlier. And even if you do engineer a way to check that a subclass or a class that included your module has implemented your "abstract" methods, it still does not save you from the case when the method implementations don't meet your expectations (L from SOLID), because a method's signature is not only its name and types of input/output, but also its behavior. This is why tests are the real solution to the problem and not some code-level checks (even static ones like in Java or C#)